# Magento 2: How can I change the frontend mobile menu position and transition

Tags: magento2, css, frontend

The mobile menu does a transition from the left side of the screen and shows a small part of the background in the right, how can I change the transition to start from the right and leave the background on the left side?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to create a new theme and override the CSS,
try whit this properties

```
.nav-sections {
    transition: right 1.3s;
    transition-property: right;
    transition-duration: 1.3s;
    transition-timing-function: ease;
}

.nav-open .nav-sections {
    left: 14%;
}
```